# How can I approximate the sum of a binomial probability times the sum's index?

Tags: calculus, statistics, summation

Is there a way to approximate $f(b)$ / remove the summation? All variables are constant except for $i$. $c$ is a probability between 0 - 1 and $a<b$. $P_i$ is a binomial probability.

$$
f(b)=\sum_{i=a}^{b}P_ii
$$

$$
P_i=\binom{b}{i}c^i(1-c)^{b-i}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your definition of your term $P_i$ is right? Because if it is the case, then $P_i$ doesn't actually depend on $i$, and your sum $f(b)$ just becomes:

$f(b) = \sum_{i=a}^b P_i i = \binom{b}{a}c^a(1-c)^{b-a} \sum_{i=a}^b i = \binom{b}{a}c^a(1-c)^{b-a} \frac{1}{2}(b(b+1)-(a-1)a)$

(using the Summation formula of Gauss)

I can imagine that you $P_i$ denotes actually $P_i = \binom{b}{i}c^i(1-c)^{b-i}$, you need to tell me :)

Comment: Sorry about that! Yes, you are correct. I have updated my question to correctly reflect the denotation of P.